# Partial View not showing(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Partial View

Here is code

```
@model IEnumerable<SmartSolutions.Models.QuestionBlock>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question1)
    </div>       
}
```

Here code for controller

```
 public ActionResult Recording(int id)
    {
        /*var items = db.QuestionBlocks
            .Where(x => x.Interview_Id == id)
            .Select(x => x).ToList();*/
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult QuestionBlock(int id) {

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var questionblocks = db.QuestionBlocks.Take(id);
        return PartialView(questionblocks);
    }
```

Here is code of View where I try to show PartialView

```
<div class="inner-div4" style="background: #ffffff">
<div class="counter-one">
    3/10
</div>
<div class="right-welcome-div2-borderless" style="background: #e5e5e5">
    <div class="timer-div-one" id="countdown" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">

    </div>
    <div class="counter-div">
    </div>
    <p>@Html.Label("Show", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "showList", @style= "cursor:pointer;", data_rows = 1 })</p>
    <div id="questions">

    </div>
```

Here is AJAX call

```
<script>
$('.showList').click(function (e) {
    var rows_num = this.getAttribute("data-rows");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/interwier/QuestionBlock",
        data: { id: rows_num },
        sucess: function (data) {
            $("#questions").html(data);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Smth wrong in controller");
        }
    });
});
```

My problem in that < when I click `<p>@Html.Label("Show", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "showList", @style= "cursor:pointer;", data_rows = 1 })</p>` I see in Network console data, but not see on View.

Comment: What is the value of this? `var questionblocks = db.QuestionBlocks.Take(id);`

Comment: If I set breakpoint it's says id=1@mariocatch

Comment: What's the value of `questionblocks` ?

Comment: Did you check what is the count of `questionblocks` ?

Comment: Yes. One block@ChetanRanpariya

Comment: I think you got the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your AJAX code: `sucess` instead of `success`. Essentially, you have no `success` method at the moment, so nothing happens with the returned response.

Comment: Flash back to grade school English: "Double the 'C', double the 'S', and you will always have *success*". ;)

Comment: This is only one of the issues. This combined with the other answer from @Nayan Dhamsaniya is the actual solution.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The action needs to actually return which view to render, and then pass in the model as the second parameter.

Comment: @mariocatch: The `data_rows` member is an *HTML attribute*, not a route param. The OP accesses this attribute in the JS and then passes `id` to the action, as required.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'm not referring to `data_rows`. I'm saying calling `return PartialView(questionblocks)` may not have been correct as we don't know what the value of `questionblocks` actually was. It could've been an int for all we know. Hard to know if that actually mapped to a partial view in his project.

Answer (score 1):

I think change parameter name **data_rows** to **id**. so please try it.

And simple changes in your method.

```
public ActionResult QuestionBlock(int id) {

    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var questionblocks = db.QuestionBlocks.Take(id);
    return PartialView("Name_Of_PartialView",questionblocks);
}
```